# A repeatedly rolling dice with square integers on faces

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A fair six-sided die whose sides are labelled $1, 4, 9, 16, 25,
36$ is rolled repeatedly until the sum of the rolled numbers is either even or a multiple of $3$.

a) Compute the probability that when we stop, the sum is odd.

b) Find the expected value of the number of rolls it takes until stopping.

Try : Let $A$ be the event that the out come is even and $B$ be the event that the outcome is a multiple of $3$. we see $n$(the total sum) can be of the form $6k,6k+1,6k+2,6k+3,6k+4,6k+5$. Thus we see $A\cup B=\{n|n=6k,6k+2,6k+3,6k+4\}$. we need to find the probability that $P(C|A\cup B)$ where $C=\{n|n=6k+3\}$. Now suppose we roll $m$ times to get an outcome $n$ then there are positive integers $a_i; i=1,2,3,..,6$ such that $\sum a_i=m;\ \sum i^2a_i=n$.
Now for a fixed $k$ how can I find the number of solns of the eqns $\sum i^2a_i=6k+l;\ l=0,2,3,4$

Comment: What do you think about the problem?

Comment: Have you covered Markov chains?

Comment: @anomaly sir i think its quite complicated. First I tried to see the sequences for the feasible set. That is we stop rolling if we get an integer of the form $6k,6k+2,6k+3,6k+4$. And we need to find the chance of conditional event $6k+3$. Suppose we roll $m$ times to get $n$ then we must have $n=6k,6k+2,6k+3,6k+4$ and $a+b+c+d+e+f=m$ and $a+4b+9c+16d+25e+36f=n$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sir what is markov chain?

Comment: @mudok, if you reframe your question to include your thoughts and work in the initial post, you will be less likely to be downvoted and more likely to have people try and work with you so you understand how to do the problem.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven sir Im new here. Im sorry if I've done something wrong. how should do whats necessary?

Comment: No problem.  Just edit your question and include the work from your comment above.  That shows that you are actively trying to solve the problem.  In many cases people who post just want answers to the homework, or perhaps a take home test.  Many people who contribute on this site are educators so don't look kindly upon that.

Comment: A long calculation with Markov chains and matrix limits gave me 1/2 for each probability. There is probably a direct argument to show that the values are equal...

Comment: Since $1\equiv 4\equiv 16\equiv 25\pmod{3}$  and $9\equiv 36\equiv 0\pmod{6}$, the end of the game is either the first roll, or the time when you've gotten three of $1,4,16,25$ where the first roll is one of these values.

Comment: Problem G2 of the [PRIMES 2017 problem set](http://math.mit.edu/research/highschool/primes/materials/2017/entpro2017usa.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I did a long calculation to get that the value was 1/2 for each probability.

We can come up with a symmetry argument pretty easily to show this, too.

If the game lasts $n$ turns, we can show that there are the same number of ways to get even as odd by listing the die rolls. Take the pairings $1\leftrightarrow 4$, $16\leftrightarrow 25$.

If $n=1$, the game ends on the first roll, then the value is $9$ or $36$, equally likely even or odd.

Then, when $n>1$ we have one value of $1,4,16,25$ in the first roll, and you swap with the corresponding number in that first roll, and get back a run of the game ending on $n$ turns with the opposite parity (since $1\cong 4\pmod 3$ and $16\cong 25\pmod 3$, this swap doesn't change when th game ends.)

So for each $n$, the number of games that end in exactly $n$ rolls are exactly equal for even and odd results.

For (b), the game either ends on the first roll, $1/3$ of the time, or, since $1\equiv 4\equiv 16\equiv 25\pmod{3}$ and $9\equiv 36\equiv 0\pmod{3}$, the game ends when the first roll is not $9,25$ and you've gotten a total of three values from $1,4,16,25$.

So the expected length is:

$$\frac{1}{3}\cdot 1 + \frac{2}{3}(1+2E)$$

where $E$ is the expected number of rolls until you get one value from $1,4,9,16$. But $E=3/2$, so the expected length of the game is:

$$\frac{9}{3}=3$$